# Where in the world are CP form macros stored?

Tags: form, macro, plugin-sproutreports, sprout

I'm using Sprout Reports, which makes this reference:

> Use the Form Macros supported by the Craft CP to keep consistent with
> the Craft UI. Sprout Reports will import the Craft CP Form Macros.
> Your Settings Template can look like this where the imported forms
> variable includes all Craft form macros defined in
> **craft/app/templates/_includes/forms.html**

Where in the world do I find this information? And is it documented anywhere?

My inquiry was prompted by needing to know how to make a form field selection required.

Comment: Here's an example of Craft using a macro to make a Text field required in the section settings. The select field would be handled the same way – adding the `required: true,` attribute to the `selectField` macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Craft Form Macro file is in the Craft package.

The `forms.html` file is the [macro file](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/794f21422068e92631b5798076ef62780ea988f1/src/templates/_includes/forms.html), and that file loads several other templates depending on which form macro is being used.

```
vendor/craftcms/cms/src/templates/_includes/forms.html
```

You can see the individual files in [this directory](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/tree/3.6.16/src/templates/_includes/forms):

```
vendor/craftcms/cms/src/templates/_includes/forms/
```

Unfortunately, there is no documentation on how these work. I'd recommend to start by getting familiar with [Twig macros](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html), and then you can look through the `vendor/craftcms/cms/src/templates` folder, various plugin template folders, or the Sprout Reports example files to see several examples of how macros are being used.